# Grouping two NumPy arrays to a dict of lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two large NumPy arrays each with shape of (519990,) that look something like this:

```
Order = array([0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 10, 14, 14, 14, 23, 23, 39]) 
Letters = array([A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L])
```

As you can see the first array is always in ascending and a positive number. I would like to group everything within the Letters to Order to turn out looking like this:

```
{0:[A,B,C], 5:[D], 6:[E], 10:[F], 14:[G, H, I], 23:[J, K], 39:[L]}
```

The code I have to do this is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['order'] = Order
df['letters'] = Letters

linearDict = df.grouby('order').apply(lambda dfg:dfg.drop('order', axis=1).to_dict(orient='list')).to_dict()

endProduct = {}
for k, v in linearDict.items():
     endProduct[k] = np.array(linearDict[k]['letter'][0:])

enProduct = {0:array([A,B,C]), 5:array([D]), 6:array([E]), 10:array([F]), 14:array([G, H, I]), 23:array([J, K]), 39:array([L])}
```

My problem is this process is BEYOND slow.  It's such a drain on the system that it causes my Jupyter Notebook to crash.  Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Is `Order` always sorted?

Comment: Order is not always sorted,

Comment: `first array is always in ascending` this means `Order` is always sorted but now you say `Order` is not sorted.

Comment: I guess you are confusing between consecutive and sorted.

Comment: @Ch3steR yes I'm so sorry, I did not initially word my question thoughtfully enough and realized I made a mistake.  it is not sorted, but it is ascending and positive but the number can be repeated various amount of times.

Comment: No worries, but when a sequence of the numbers are in ascending order then they are sorted. You are confusing between sorted and consecutive. **sorting** is ordering the sequence of numbers in either **ascending** or **descending order**.

Comment: @Ch3steR thank you for teaching me this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We could leverage the fact that `Order` is sorted, to simply slice `Letters` after getting the *intervaled-indices*, like so -

```
def numpy_slice(Order, Letters):
    Order = np.asarray(Order)
    Letters = np.asarray(Letters)
    idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,Order[:-1]!=Order[1:],True])
    return {Order[i]:Letters[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(idx[:-1],idx[1:])}
```

Sample run -

```
In [66]: Order
Out[66]: array([16, 16, 16, 16, 23, 30, 33, 33, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39])

In [67]: Letters
Out[67]: 
array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
       'N', 'O'], dtype='<U1')

In [68]: numpy_slice(Order, Letters)
Out[68]: 
{16: array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype='<U1'),
 23: array(['E'], dtype='<U1'),
 30: array(['F'], dtype='<U1'),
 33: array(['G', 'H'], dtype='<U1'),
 39: array(['I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'], dtype='<U1')}
```

Comment: hi, actually Order is not sorted, I'm sorry I should have been more clear in my post.  Order can look like this:
```
Order = array([16, 16, 16, 16, 23, 30, 33, 33, 39, 39, 39, 39,39,39, 39)
```
it will always be in ascending order but can skip around.  I will need the corresponding array to group together with the number in the Order array. where it would turn out:
```
{16: [A, B, C, D], 23:[F], 30:[G], 33: [H, I], 39: [J, K, L, M, N, O, P]}
```

Comment: Hi, I apologize, I realize I didn't word it correctly.  Order will always be ascending and positive number only.  So it could be like [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 10, 11, 11, 22, 25, 25, 30].

Comment: @Shion It should still work. Added sample run. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Divakar I just ran this and it returned only single-element arrays associated with the Key, but it sure did it fast!

Comment: @Shion `Order` and `Letters` are two NumPy arrays with same lengths, right?

Comment: @Divakar yes they are of the same length

Comment: @Shion Asking again, are they both NumPy arrays?

Comment: @Divakar yes they are both numpy arrays.

Comment: @Shion If you are getting just single element output, most probably it has to be lists. I added a generic solution that handles lists and arrays alike. Let me know if this works?

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
data = df.groupby('order')['letters'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

We can further improve the performance by passing `sort=False` and agg to `tuple` instead of `list`:

```
data = df.groupby('order', sort=False)['letters'].agg(tuple).to_dict()
```

Result:

```
# print(data)
{0: ['A', 'B', 'C'], 1: ['D', 'E', 'F'], 2: ['G', 'H', 'I'], 3: ['J', 'K', 'L']}
```

`timeit` performance results:

```
df.shape    
(1200000, 2)

o = np.repeat([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 100000)
l = np.repeat([A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L], 100000)

***Fastest answer***
%%timeit -n10 @Divakar
idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,o[:-1]!=o[1:],True])
{o[i]:l[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(idx[:-1],idx[1:])}
1.44 ms ± 243 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
*******************

%%timeit -n10 @Scott
grp = np.cumsum(np.unique(o, return_counts=True)[1])
arr = np.stack(np.split(l, grp)[:-1])
{n: k for n, k in enumerate(arr.tolist())}
38.5 ms ± 699 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit -n10 @ shubham 2
data = df.groupby('order', sort=False)['letters'].agg(tuple).to_dict()
118 ms ± 3.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit -n10 @shubham 1
data = df.groupby('order')['letters'].agg(list).to_dict()
177 ms ± 4.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit -n10 @anky 1
d = (dict([*chain(*map(dict.items,[{k:[*zip(*g)][1] } 
     for k,g in groupby(zip(o,l),itemgetter(0))]))]))
636 ms ± 23.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit -n10 @ anky 2
_ = dict([(k,list(zip(*g))[1]) for k,g in groupby(zip(o,l),itemgetter(0))])
659 ms ± 36.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit -n10 @Ch3ster
new = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in zip(o, l):
    new[k].append(v)
602 ms ± 1.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Hey, shubham can test my approach too and add timeit results?

Comment: @Ch3steR Sure, I guess you have tested all the answers already. But i will definitely try your answer, give me some time.

Comment: @Ch3steR On large arrays you approach is slowing things a little bit down, i will add the results to my post, give me some time.

Comment: Thank you, actually, I made a typo while benchmarking. My approach with large arrays is slow.

Comment: Nothing to worry. ;).

Comment: @ch3ster Thanks, actually i liked your answer  and is fast enough (even faster than other answers) when we operate on arrays of smaller sizes.

Comment: Thank you but OP's operating on an array of size 500K so, might not be the correct to post my solution so deleted it and it might distract the future reader from the answers you and Scott provided.

Comment: @anky yes i will surely add.

Comment: Good to know @anky, i didn't knew about that.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
grp = np.cumsum(np.unique(Order, return_counts=True)[1])
arr = np.stack(np.split(Letters, grp)[:-1])
{n: k for n, k in enumerate(arr.tolist())}
```

Output:

```
{0: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
 1: ['D', 'E', 'F'],
 2: ['G', 'H', 'I'],
 3: ['J', 'K', 'L']}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work with uneven number in groups... And you might need to sort the arrays first.  I think this answer is to narrow need to make it more robust.

Comment: hi, thank you so much to everyone for their responses.  There are times when the Order array will have [16,16,16,16,16,22,22,33,45] so the result will need to have the arrays of uneven shapes.

Answer (score 5):

May be this can be optimized (haven't tested for speed too but should be fast) more but another approach is itertools groupby:

```
from itertools import chain,groupby
from operator import itemgetter
```

---

```
d = (dict([*chain(*map(dict.items,[{k:[*zip(*g)][1] } 
     for k,g in groupby(zip(Order,Letters),itemgetter(0))]))]))
```

Or without chain , should be faster than before:

```
dict([(k,list(zip(*g))[1]) for k,g in groupby(zip(Order,Letters),itemgetter(0))])
```

---

```
{0: ('A', 'B', 'C'),
 1: ('D', 'E', 'F'),
 2: ('G', 'H', 'I'),
 3: ('J', 'K', 'L')}
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Anky's, yours and my answer are generalized they work with an unsorted and uneven-numbered group. While divakar's and Scott's solutions leverage on the fact that `Order` is always sorted.

Comment: @Ch3ster yep.. its generalized and don not required ordering to be maintained.